# Bivariate Normal Distribution Mean

Tags: normal-distribution, mean, bivariate

$X$ and $Y$ have bivariate normal distribution and have joint pdf
\begin{equation*}
f\left( x,y\right) =a\exp \left( \frac{-1}{2}\omega \right) ,\text{where }%
\omega =6x^{2}+12y^{2}-16xy-8x+24
\end{equation*}
then what are the means of $X$ and $Y$?

I have 
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{\left( 1-\rho ^{2}\right) \sigma _{X}^{2}}=6,~\frac{1}{\left(
1-\rho ^{2}\right) \sigma _{Y}^{2}}=12~\text{and }\frac{-2\rho }{\left(
1-\rho ^{2}\right) \sigma _{X}\sigma _{Y}}=-16
\end{equation*}
so i can find $\rho ,\sigma _{X}$ and $\sigma _{Y}$ using these equations.
But how can i get $\mu _{X}$ and $\mu _{Y}$?

this question asked in an exam and requested to be replied in 2 minutes. Is there a shortcut for this?

Comment: Match the theoretical expression of a joint density of two correlated normals, to what you have, and see where it gets you.

Comment: i have already tried that way  and i know i can get the result using matching. But this question asked in an exam and requested to be replied in 2 minutes.

Comment: Do the means coincide with the point where the density is maximized? If so you have a shortcut

Comment: Just minimize the function $\omega$ over (x, y), which I think gives you (6, 4)

Comment: I think this works: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution the mode of a multivariate normal is $\mu$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The means coincide with the point where the density is maximized. See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution: the mode of a multivariate normal is $\mu$.

The shortcut is therefore to minimize the function ω over $(x, y)$, which gives $\mu = (6, 4)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: As Adrian points out, we need to minimize $\omega$ as a function of
$x$ and $y$. Now, 
\begin{align}
\omega(x) &= 6x^2 - x(16y+8) + \cdots\\
\omega(y) &= 12y^2 - y(16x) + \cdots
\end{align}
have minima at 
$$x = \frac{16y+8}{12} = \frac 43y + \frac 23, \quad y = \frac{16x}{24} = \frac{2}{3}x$$ respectively, giving $(x,y) = (6,4)$ as the solution.
Here, instead of the calculus-based method of finding minima,
I used the fact that $ax^2+bx+c$ has an extremum at the
average value of its roots $\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ which average equals $\frac{-b}{2a}$ (no need to fuss with evaluating the square root). I leave
it up to you to determine if this is doable in 2 minutes or not.